# Button Styles via xaml and expression blend

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, blend

I created a custom control that looks a lot like the tab buttons in VS 2012. In my control I could set a propertiy to posistion the text and sidebar vertical or horizontal. After playing around with the control I figured there was probably a better way to go about this.  So i fired up the Expression Blend preview and suprising enough (only second or third time using blend) was able to create a style to achieve a simliar style button.  However, Now I  want to have control over the text and sidebar being vertical or horizontal.  I would also like to have control over the mouse over color.  Is this possible to do via one style or am i going to have to create a bunch of different styles?

Comment: Could you explain those last three lines better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you can achieve what you want to do with [event triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger.aspx).